# Python print statement with both % (percentage) and format specifier included

Tags: python, format-specifiers

I want to print a statement like

*Prediction is 30.03%*

I am trying to use

```
print("Prediction is %0.2f %"%30.03)
```

which gives me

> ValueError: incomplete format

I tried

```
print("Prediction is %0.2f \%"%30.03)
```

which gives me the same error

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You escape the `%` with another `%`:

```
print("Prediction is %0.2f %%" % 30.03)
#                          ^^
#           Note extra % here
```